# making the xar utility use expat instead of libxml2

Tags: freebsd, libxml2, expat-parser

From the xar utilities source code, it looks like it can use either the expat or libxml2 XML parsers

```
#if HAVE_LIBXML_XMLREADER_H 
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h> 
#elif HAVE_BSDXML_H 
#include <bsdxml.h> 
#elif HAVE_EXPAT_H 
#include <expat.h>
```

How do I get it to use expat instead of libxml when I install it using ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version (1.5.2 as of this writing) *requires* libxml.

The word `expat` doesn't even occur in the source code.

Comment: This file in the latest stable version of FreeBSD still uses Expat  https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/contrib/libarchive/libarchive/archive_read_support_format_xar.c?revision=229592&view=markup. Isn't this used by the xar utility?

Comment: @SivaDotRender That is `libarchive`, a component of the FreeBSD base system. It is used by e.g. FreeBSD's `tar` and `cpio`. It has *nothing* to do with `xar`, which is available from ports (`/usr/ports/archivers/xar`).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!